# Initializing camera for list of available cameras in Future

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using this code that I got directly from pub.dev regarding initializing the camera and creating a list of available cameras

the list is created in a Future main() function but it is not being automatically called when I navigate to the CameraApp page.  Has anyone run into this issue?  How do I initialize the camera and create the list of available cameras when it navigates to the page with this code?  Please help, thank you.

```
/// CameraApp is the Main Application.
class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Default Constructor
  const CameraApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: CameraExampleHome(),
    );
  }
}

List<CameraDescription> _cameras = <CameraDescription>[];

Future<void> main() async {
  // Fetch the available cameras before initializing the app.
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    _cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    _logError(e.code, e.description);
  }
  runApp(const CameraApp());
}
```

And this is the code where I call the CameraApp function from inside a button:

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () 
              {Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => CameraApp()));},
              child: const Text('Camera'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  minimumSize: const Size(160.0, 35.0)),

            ),
```

Comment: Sorry if my problem is unclear I am trying to initialize and the list of cameras in cameras_ but when I call the CameraApp function the Future main() function that gets the list is not executed.

Comment: Can someone please just help me and let me know if the camera should always be initialized in the main(), I am trying to do it outside and it is causing me this problem.  And if its possible to initialize outside of the main() what is the correct structure?

Comment: Still hoping to get an answer on this, when the example code is used from pub.dev it works fine in one file but to split the code in different components causes errors.

Comment: okay. What about initializing and storing the cameras (and controllers) with some service file in main. Then in the CameraApp, you access the cameras from this service?

Comment: did you try making the initializer call in initState of the CameraApp file

Comment: Thanks @ObumunemeNwabude I am trying to keep my code fairly organized so my question is if I initialize the camera object in the main would I have to pass it down to screen where I use it in a provider?

Comment: Technically, yes. You need a state management method to keep the camera reference. You already mentioned Provider and you can use it. If you don't wan't to use it, you could use InheritedWidget or Riverpod. As you want your code to be clean you can use the service locator pattern. [This answer should give you insights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72945522/13644299). But then instead of Navigation you will use Camera instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @ObumunemeNwabude i looked through the link you sent but am still a little confused which function to wrap in a provider and when and where to notifyListeners.  Could you please provide a code example

Comment: main() is the entrypoint to the app. It is only called once when the app is started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things to consider here.. The implementation you did was right but you named the cameras as a private variable which will be accessed in a single dart file by adding an _ like _cameras. Removing that will make it globally available in all classes just by importing main.dart

Here is the full code

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:trial/CameraExampleHome.dart';

List<CameraDescription> cameras = <CameraDescription>[];
void main() async {
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    cameras = await availableCameras();
    print(cameras);
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: CameraApp());
  }
}

class CameraApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Default Constructor
  const CameraApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: CameraExampleHome(),
    );
  }
}
```

**cameraExampleHome.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'main.dart';

class CameraExampleHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraExampleHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CameraExampleHome> createState() => _CameraExampleHomeState();
}

class _CameraExampleHomeState extends State<CameraExampleHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Available Cameras $cameras"),
//output: Available Cameras [CameraDescription(0, CameraLensDirection.back, 90), CameraDescription(1, CameraLensDirection.front, 270), CameraDescription(2, CameraLensDirection.front, 270)]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @KaushikChandru but is it good coding style to import the main?  I always was taught that was bad practice

Comment: But you have defined the List of cameras in the root level in main.dart.. You can move it to some other dart file, if you wish to keep it at the root level and can still access it in main.dart. The best practice to hold this variable is to create a singleton. But this is an easy approach

Comment: Did it work as expected?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a kind of singleton to manage camera operations.

```
class CameraManager {
  // Declare your camera list here
  List<CameraDescription> _cameras = <CameraDescription>[];

  // Constructor
  CameraManager._privateConstructor() {}

  // initialise instance
  static final CameraManager instance =
      CameraManager._privateConstructor();

  // Add a getter to access camera list
  List<CameraDescription> get cameras => _cameras;

  // Init method
  init() async {
    try {
      _cameras = await availableCameras();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _logError(e.code, e.description);
    }
  }

  // other needed methods to manage camera
  ...
}
```

And then in you main function

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // Fetch the available cameras before initializing the app.
  try {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await CameraManager.instance.init();
  }
  runApp(const CameraApp());
}
```

Then on other part of your application, you can import the singleton and access methods and properties with `CameraManager.instance.*`, for example `CameraManager.instance.cameras` access `_cameras` through the getter.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a library file for Global Variables.

Create a file called "globals.dart" in your lib folder.

Declare the following line at the top.

```
library your_project_name.globals;
```

Then set your variable in it

```
List<CameraDescription> cameras = <CameraDescription>[];
```

Usage in main

```
import 'globals.dart' as globals;

main() {
  ...
  globals.cameras = await availableCameras();
  ...
}
```

Then simply use the variable anywhere in your project.

```
import 'globals.dart' as globals;

globals.cameras...
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare list of CameraDescription global instance as below:

```
  List<CameraDescription> cameras = <CameraDescription>[];
```

Now you can access the camera instance by importing main.dart , _ always make the instance variable private which will not be accessible outside the file