# Routes are not recognized inside GetMaterialApp.router

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-routes

I need to add named routes to my app but inside `GetMaterialApp.router` I don't have the option for `onGenerateRoute` and now when I try to push a named route I get the following error:

```
FlutterError (Navigator.onGenerateRoute was null, but the route named "/main/noticeProblem" was referenced.
To use the Navigator API with named routes (pushNamed, pushReplacementNamed, or pushNamedAndRemoveUntil), the Navigator must be provided with an onGenerateRoute handler.
```

I've searched but didn't find a way to fix this

And this is the code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
          name: '/main',
          page: () => MenuScreen(),
          middlewares: [FirstRunMiddleware()],
          children: [
            GetPage(
              name: '/noticeProblem',
              transition: Transition.leftToRight,
              page: () => MainNoticeUi(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        GetPage(name: '/intro', page: () => const IntroPages()),
        GetPage(name: '/settings', page: () => const AppSettings()),
      ],
    );
  }
```

And this is how I try to push the new page on the stack:

```
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Get.toNamed('/main/noticeProblem'); 
        // Get.to(MainNoticeUi()); works as expected but I need to use named routes
      },
      ...
);
```

Any ways on how I can generate those routes?

P.S: I need to use `GetMaterialPage.router` because this `middleware: FirstRunMiddleware()` has to be `async`

Answer (score 2):

After 4 hours of searching I have found a solution, instead of this `Get.toNamed('/main/noticeProblem');`, I have to use `Get.rootDelegate.toNamed('/main/noticeProblem');`

Comment: thanks for this I have been working on a similar problem for a long time.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926880/how-do-i-automatically-route-when-in-flutter-from-within-main/72945522?noredirect=1#comment128850446_72945522. what does .rootDelegate do?