# No GoRouter found in context after adding GetX in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-getx

I get the following app when trying to navigate in my Flutter app.

Up to now, it worked as expected: selecting a button routed correctly.

But, I needed a way from within main() to go to a route based on a Deep Link event.  But because there was no context, I added routing using the GetX package.

How I get this:

```
Unhandled Exception: 'package:go_router/src/go_router.dart': Failed assertion: line 146 pos 12: 'inherited != null': No GoRouter found in context
```

I am guessing there is collision between how GetX and GoRouter route....?

If so, suggestions on how to route when a condition is met in main()?

I wrote up more details here as well as my code: [How do I automatically route when in Flutter from within main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926880/how-do-i-automatically-route-when-in-flutter-from-within-main/72945522?noredirect=1#comment128850446_72945522)

Comment: hi, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I used a package called event to published the event and then route. It mostly worked when the app was already installed but when the app needed to be downloaded first it wasn’t clear where the event was emitted

Answer (score 2):

using `Get.context` worked for me when navigating from a controller for example:
`GoRouter.of(Get.context!).go('/search');`

Answer (score 1):

Just checking as a potential cause of the error - What does your `main.dart` file look like?

Are you using `MaterialApp.router(...)` or `GetMaterialApp(...)` ?

Comment: I think I used GetMaterialApp to make it work, but that broken things so went back to MaterialPApp.  I ended up publishing an event to solve it.