# Flutter : How to close alertdialog from another file

Tags: flutter

I have 2 dart file. I want close the alertdialog from another dart file in specific conditions.
How can I ?

for example the function i want.(I wrote to express myself better.)

```
 void example(){
    if(control==false){
        alertDialog.close();
  }
```

Alert dialog file

```
class AlertForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AlertFormState createState() => _AlertFormState();
}

class _AlertFormState extends State<AlertForm> {

    void _showDialog() {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
          content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

So what I want is to use the pop action in a function in another flutter file.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Navigator.of(context).pop();` inside the if block (of the void example function of the other Dart file) and the alert should close.

But here is the problem, the context above might not be part of or aware of the dialog and the above may not work.

More info about your setup would suggest a solution to this problem. Like how exactly does the other Dart file exist relative to the file where `_showDialog` is declared? If it's something you can easily provide context from AlertForm Dart file to the closingDialog Dart file, then you should know what to do. If that's not the case then a navigator key should help.

You can keep a navigator key for the entire application. Then instead of closing the dialog with `Navigator.of(context).pop();`, you use `navigatorKey.currentState!.pop();`.

You should have properly setup the navigator key yourself. Refer to this Stackoverflow answer for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72945522/13644299

It is not compulsory to use get_it package. You can simply export the NavigationService (that will keep the navigatorKey) from any Dart file or with any method you deem fit, depending on your current state management architecture.